# 32-bit addressing problems in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I started to learn assembly and I have met with problems related to absolute address 32-bit. I have read recently post about this similar problem [Why is there problems with absolute addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68053847/15566979). Can you prompt why if I specify without writing `default rel` I get error related with that executable base address in mac os starts 4GB.

```
mov qword[test], ‘hello’
```

To summarize all, problem is why is `mov qword[test], ‘hello’` a 32-bit addressing? And if I specify before  `mov qword[test], ‘hello’` this `REX.W` it doesn’t help me to solve 32-bit addressing problem?

Thank you

Comment: it is 32 bit because the instruction encoding only supports 32 bits for the address. Relative addressing uses `rip+offset` (also 32 bit). You can tell nasm with the `rel` keyword or `default rel` if you want relative. Note that `qword [test]` refers to the operation size, not the address size.

Comment: So as I understand if I wanna refer to address which is located above 32 bit address I can do only that through offset from RIP?

Comment: Yes, or indirectly.

Comment: Because the only ways to encode that are `[disp32]` or `[rip+rel32]`.  See [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101).  My answer on [Why are global variables in x86-64 accessed relative to the instruction pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56262889) includes an explanation of how RIP-relative works in machine code.

Comment: Why is there a problem?  Because MacOS maps executables outside the low 4GiB of address space.  (Perhaps as a way to make sure that truncating pointers to 32-bit always faults, not accesses some other memory.)