# CS: override on access to global variables in IDA output, like mov eax, cs:x?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, ida, addressing-mode

I am writing simple programs then analyze them.
Today I've written this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int x;
 
int main(void){
    printf("Enter X:\n");
 
    scanf("%d",&x);
 
    printf("You enter %d...\n",x);
 
    return 0;
}
```

It's compiled into this:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
lea     rdi, s          ; "Enter X:"
call    _puts
lea     rsi, x
lea     rdi, aD         ; "%d"
mov     eax, 0
call    ___isoc99_scanf
mov     eax, cs:x   <- don't understand this
mov     esi, eax
lea     rdi, format     ; "You enter %d...\n"
mov     eax, 0
call    _printf
mov     eax, 0
pop     rbp
retn
```

I don't understand what `cs:x` means.
I use Ubuntu x64, GCC 10.3.0, and IDA pro 7.6.

Comment: Which disassembler did you use `cs:` is a segment prefix override but it's pretty useless in this context (also it's probably RO, IIRC). If you check the bytes of the instruction you can see if the prefix it's actually there (weird) or if the disassembler made it up (also weird).

Comment: @MargaretBloom I use Ida pro 7.6

Comment: @MargaretBloom U was right, ghidra show me this -> MOV        EAX,dword ptr [x] . I was thinking Ida pro was best interactive disas

Comment: ah, ok. It's just the IDA way to tell you it's a RIP relative address. Despite using it regularly, I've never noticed it. I'm writing a short answer.

Comment: examine the machine code as well not just what some disassembler outputs, esp for x86 where it is difficult to impossible to reliably disassemble.

Comment: @old_timer: Yes examine the machine code, but there's no reason to think anything went wrong when disassembling GCC output.  You always post comments about the theoretical impossibility of decoding x86, but 99.9% of the time that's just FUD, and isn't a problem for the kinds of cases you're posting about.

Comment: from the machine code could just look it up in the intel docs rather than asking here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL:DR: IDA confusingly uses `cs:` to indicate a RIP-relative addressing mode in 64-bit code.

---

In IDA `mov eax, x` means `mov eax, DWORD [x]` which in turn means reading a DWORD from the variable `x`.
For completeness, `mov rax, OFFSET x` means `mov rax, x` (i.e. putting the address of `x` in `rax`).

In 64-bit displacements are still 32-bit, so, for a Position Independent Executable, it's not always possible to address a variable by encoding its address (because it's 64-bit and it would not fit into a 32-bit field).  And in position-independent code, it's not desirable.
Instead, [RIP-relative addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262889/why-are-global-variables-in-x86-64-accessed-relative-to-the-instruction-pointer) is used.

In NASM, RIP-relative addressing takes the form `mov eax, [REL x]`, in gas it is `mov x(%rip), %eax`.
Also, in NASM, if `DEFAULT REL` is active, the instruction can be shortened to `mov eax, [x]` which is identical to the 32-bit syntax.

Each disassembler will disassemble a RIP-relative operand differently.  As you commented, Ghidra gives `mov eax, DWORD PTR [x]`.
IDA uses `mov eax, cs:x` to mean `mov eax, [REL x]`/`mov x(%rip), %eax`.

```
;IDA listing, 64-bit code
mov eax, x                ;This is mov eax, [x] in NASM and most likely wrong unless your exec is not PIE and always loaded <= 4GiB
mov eax, cs:x             ;This is mov eax, [REL x] in NASM and idiomatic to 64-bit programs
```

In short, you can mostly ignore the `cs:` because that's just the way variables are addressed in 64-bit mode.
Of course, as the listing above shows, the use or absence of RIP-relative addressing tells you the program can be loaded anywhere or just below the 4GiB.

---

The `cs` prefix shown by IDA threw me off.

I can see that it could mentally resemble "code" and thus the `rip` register but I don't think the RIP-relative addressing implies a `cs` segment override.

In 32-bit mode, the code segment is usually read-only, so an instruction like `mov [cs:x], eax` will fault.
In this scenario, putting a `cs:` in front of the operand would be wrong.

**In 64-bit mode**, segment overrides (other than `fs`/`gs`) are ignored (and the read-bit of the code segment is ignored anyway), so the presence of a `cs:` doesn't really matter because `ds` and `cs` are effectively indistinguishable.  (Even an `ss` or `ds` override doesn't change the #GP or #SS exception for a non-canonical address.)
Probably the AGU doesn't even read the segment shadow registers anymore for segment bases other than `fs` or `gs`.  (Although even in 32-bit mode, there's a lower latency fast path for the normal case of segment base = 0, so hardware may just let that do its job.)

**Still `cs:` is misleading in my opinion** - a `2E` prefix byte is still possible in machine code as padding.  Most tools still call it a CS prefix, although http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html calls it a "null prefix" in 64-bit mode.  There's no such byte here, and `cs:` is not an obvious or clear way to imply RIP-relative addressing.

Comment: IDA seems totally inconsistent, not using `cs:` in `lea  rdi, format` which is also certainly using RIP-relative addressing.  (This is GCC output, so if it was using 32-bit absolute it would have used `mov edi, OFFSET format`).  It seems to be pretty much GNU `.intel_syntax`, although I guess it's actually the same syntax that it uses on Windows, and thus won't use `[RIP + format]` because it's more like actual MASM.  Overall seems  like bad choices for a disassembler that you'd want to use on obfuscated / hand-crafted machine code.

Comment: What would IDA show if your machine code actually did have a CS override prefix?

Comment: @PeterCordes A `db` instruction before the actual instruction. I too was curious and tried it.