# What is the outcome of mov on non bracket memory locations?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, intel, ida

I am having problems distinguishing whether the address is loaded or the content from the address. Please help me clarify.

```
1. mov     [rsp+78h+arg_0], rsi
2. mov     rsi, cs:qword_1F39B60
3. mov     [rsp+78h+arg_38], rsi
```

On line 2, is it loading `1F39B60` in `rsi` or the contents of `1F39B60` in `rsi`?

Would `lea rsi, [qword_1F39B60]` be the same?

If non bracket using `mov` action on a memory even allowed or this is just a visual IDA thing?

Can you explain to me why it shows `cs:` even though `qword_1F39B60` is in the `.data` segment? Shouldn't it be `ds:`?

Last but not the least is `rsp+78h` a fancy way of saying `rbp` by the disassembler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On line 2, is it loading `1F39B60` in `rsi` or the contents of `1F39B60` in `rsi`?

Let's assume that `qword_1F39B60` is a pseudolabel defined by your disassembler somewhere in code section and that address of this label is linked at the virtual address `0x01F39B60`. This is the number which will be loaded to `rsi` then.

> Would lea rsi, [qword_1F39B60] be the same?

Yes.

> Is non bracket using `mov` action on a memory even allowed or this is just a visual IDA thing?

Yes, but the meaning depends on the assembler.  IDA syntax is MASM-style, like the GNU assembler's Intel syntax.  `mov reg, name` is a load just like `mov reg,[name]`, loading the register from a memory location.  See [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32)

In many other more sane assemblers, `mov reg, name` loads the register with address of that symbol/label.  The (relocated) address is expressed in instruction encoding as an immediate operand.  (The MASM syntax for this is `mov reg,OFFSET mem` to load `reg` with the offset of symbol `mem` expressed as an immediate number).  In 64-bit code you'll more often see a RIP-relative LEA to put an address into a register.

> Can you explain to me why it shows `cs:` even though `qword_1F39B60` is in the .data segment? Shouldn't it be ds:?

As Margaret Bloom explains in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702174/cs-override-on-access-to-global-variables-in-ida-output-like-mov-eax-csx), using prefix `cs` in `mov rsi, cs:qword_1F39B60` is IDA's stupid way to actually express that `rsi` is loaded with 8 bytes from memory addressed **relative** to `rip`, if it was encoded as `48 8B 35 rel32`. According to [MOV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) documentation it is the `MOV r64,r/m64` form with relative encoding `REX.W + 8B /r` which works only for addresses withing 2 GB range above|below `rip`.
ModR/M=35h (mod=00b,reg=110b,r/m=101b) specifies RIP-relative encoding in 64bit mode, as [Table 2-7](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) says.

In 64bit mode the contents of `cs,ds,es,ss` are irrelevant; those segment override prefixes are fully ignored.  But if one was present, you'd see it in the encoding.
If it is `BE609BF301`, is should be disassembled as `mov rsi,qword_1F39B60`.
If it is `2E488B3425609BF301`, it corresponds with `mov rsi,[cs:1F39B60h]`, according to Nasm disassembler.  That's why it's so weird that IDA uses `cs:` to mean something else, when you'd expect it would only be used to indicate a `2E` CS prefix in the machine code.

> Last but not the least is `rsp+78h` a fancy way of saying `rbp` by the disassembler?

No. Disassembler never knows whether `rbp=rsp+78h` (without a very sophisticated heuristic analysis).

Comment: `mov     rsi, cs:qword_1F39B60` wouldn't normally be described as an immediate operand.  It's a memory operand using a `[RIP + rel32]` addressing mode to access that memory location, @Sawb.  (IIRC, `cs:label` is the arbitrary weird syntax choice IDA uses to indicate RIP-relative.)  The 4-byte relative displacement is part of the machine code for the instruction, and in a general computer-architecture sense could be said to be immediate, but the whole *operand* is not immediate.  That would be `mov rsi, OFFSET qword_1F39B60` for a 32 or 64-bit absolute immediate, in MASM-like syntax.

Comment: @Sawb: See the linked duplicate, Margaret Bloom checked what IDA does for some known machine code, so we could figure out what it's disassembly means.  Yes, it should be DS:, the CS: is total nonsense.  There's almost certainly no CS prefix by in the machine code, and if there was it wouldn't do *anything* because it's 64-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes just to make sure I read it correct, that does mean vitsoft is not correct and cs:qword_1F39B60 that is a rip relative will access the content of 1F39B60?

Comment: @Sawb: Yes, memory operand with a rip-relative addressing mode, accessing that address.  Parts of this answer are wrong.  The downvote on it is mine.  `mov reg, symbol` being a mov-immediate is how NASM syntax works, but from the `cs:` there we can see this NASM-style or euroassembler syntax.

Comment: (typo in last comment: we can this **isn't** NASM or €ASM)

Comment: Re: your edit: In MASM-style syntax, `mov     rsi, qword_1F39B60` is still a load, since it's a symbol name, not an actual number.  To get a mov-immediate you'd need `mov     rsi, OFFSET qword_1F39B60`.  Also,  `MOV r64,r/m64` using an absolute `[sign_extended_disp32]` can address the low 2 GiB and the high 2 GiB of 64-bit address space, not the low 4.  Unless you used an address-size prefix to truncate the address to 32 bits (and implicitly *zero* extend).