# String at specific address with non-printable ASCII values

Tags: c, assembly, ascii, non-printing-characters, binary-bomb

I have an assignment that includes a bomb with different phases. I have a **bomb.c** and I will try to solve this assignment phases with assembly and gdb. I am trying to give the correct input string to the program. If the input string is correct then the bomb defuses for that phase. In the first phase, as I understand from the assembly version, it will compare the input (which I will enter) with the string at the address (which is `0x1bbc` in this case.) when I try to find the string at that address, in one approach it gave me `"H\215\065\274\033"` ASCII values for chars of the string. but some of them are non printable. how can I find the specific string at that address? can you help?

I used `x/s` command for the specific address, it gave me these ASCII values.

```
User
0000000000001b7f <strings_not_equal>:
    1b7f:       f3 0f 1e fa             repz nop %edx
    1b83:       41 54                   push   %r12
    1b85:       55                      push   %rbp
    1b86:       53                      push   %rbx
    1b87:       48 89 fb                mov    %rdi,%rbx
    1b8a:       48 89 f5                mov    %rsi,%rbp
    1b8d:       e8 cc ff ff ff          callq  1b5e <string_length>
    1b92:       41 89 c4                mov    %eax,%r12d
    1b95:       48 89 ef                mov    %rbp,%rdi
    1b98:       e8 c1 ff ff ff          callq  1b5e <string_length>
    1b9d:       89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
    1b9f:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    1ba4:       41 39 d4                cmp    %edx,%r12d
    1ba7:       75 31                   jne    1bda <strings_not_equal+0x5b>
    1ba9:       0f b6 13                movzbl (%rbx),%edx
    1bac:       84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
    1bae:       74 1e                   je     1bce <strings_not_equal+0x4f>
    1bb0:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1bb5:       38 54 05 00             cmp    %dl,0x0(%rbp,%rax,1)
    1bb9:       75 1a                   jne    1bd5 <strings_not_equal+0x56>
    1bbb:       48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
    1bbf:       0f b6 14 03             movzbl (%rbx,%rax,1),%edx
    1bc3:       84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
    1bc5:       75 ee                   jne    1bb5 <strings_not_equal+0x36>
    1bc7:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1bcc:       eb 0c                   jmp    1bda <strings_not_equal+0x5b>
    1bce:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1bd3:       eb 05                   jmp    1bda <strings_not_equal+0x5b>
    1bd5:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    1bda:       5b                      pop    %rbx
    1bdb:       5d                      pop    %rbp
    1bdc:       41 5c                   pop    %r12
    1bde:       c3                      retq



00000000000015b5 <phase_1>:
    15b5:       f3 0f 1e fa             repz nop %edx
    15b9:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    15bd:       48 8d 35 bc 1b 00 00    lea    0x1bbc(%rip),%rsi        # 3180 <_IO_stdin_used+0x180>
    15c4:       e8 b6 05 00 00          callq  1b7f <strings_not_equal>
    15c9:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
    15cb:       75 05                   jne    15d2 <phase_1+0x1d>
    15cd:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
    15d1:       c3                      retq
    15d2:       e8 4f 08 00 00          callq  1e26 <explode_bomb>
    15d7:       eb f4                   jmp    15cd <phase_1+0x18>
```

This part is corresponding assembly version.
To determine the content of the string that the address 0x1bbc(%rip) points to I did that:
()btw I dont remeber the way but somehow I reach the 0x15bd in order to find the string

```
(gdb) x/s 0x15bd
```

it gave: H\215\065\274\033

Comment: since I dont have enough right trial I didn't put any code line but I try to share some command that I used before.

Comment: this is the bomb lab assignment. common in universities for computer organization courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to this line:

```
15bd:       48 8d 35 bc 1b 00 00    lea    0x1bbc(%rip),%rsi        # 3180 <_IO_stdin_used+0x180>
```

The addressing mode used is IP relative, which is common for objects instantiated in the code segment and for global and static data in the data segment that follows. This is consistent with this address being that of a string literal.

The offset `0x1bbc` should be added to the address of the next instruction, `0x15c4`, and the disassembler did the math for you in the comment: the address where you can find the string is `0x3180`. You should get the string in text with:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x3180
```

Comment: when I use ````x/s```` command with this address, it says out of bounds. what can be right approach to use that address in order to find the string?

Comment: RIP-relative addressing is used for static data in any section, including `.data` or `.bss`.  ([Why are global variables in x86-64 accessed relative to the instruction pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56262889)).  Also, `.rodata` gets linked into a separate segment than `.text` these days, so it can be non-executable.  So it's not the code segment.  The only time you wouldn't get just an LEA is for a shared library accessing non-`hidden` global variables, since they'll live in the main executable if it references them, so not a link-time-constant distance.

Comment: You may need to run the C startup code before you can read from this location: set a breakpoint on `main` and run the program, then examine the data with the `x/s` command.

Comment: This is a PIE executable; you can tell from the tiny addresses (starting around 1K).  After `run`, `0x3180` won't be the right address anymore; you'd want to disassemble `phase_1` again to see the new target address for the LEA after the executable has been mapped to `0x0000555555...` (GDB disabled ASLR by default so it'll always be the  same base address.)  In GDB, it should work to do `x /s 0x3180` if you *haven't* `run` the program: even though there is no process and thus no actual memory, GDB can fake it for addresses backed by real sections of the executable.

Comment: fyi, after ```(gdb) b main  (gdb) run
(gdb) x/s 0x3180``` it still gives out of bounds

Comment: @zeliha: follow *Peter Cordes* advice: either dump the memory before running the executable or set the breakpoint and run til `main` and disassemble `phase_1` again to see at which address the program was actually loaded.

Comment: @zeliha: See the last edit and my previous comment: `run` changes the address of everything (code and data).  `x/s 0x3180` *should* work if you have *not* done `run` yet this GDB session.  After `run`, `x/s` with the true address shown from `disas phase_1` will definitely work.

Comment: It worked now. I started a new GDB session and ran the ```x/s 0x3180``` command. My bomb defused :)) THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ALL OF YOUR HELP!!